# my navbar img dont support float left in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

i code a navbar and use bootstrap for that with this code

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=divice-width ,intial-scale=1">
<title>complete bootstrap 4 website layout</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/popper.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.13.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-Bfad6CLCknfcloXFOyFnlgtENryhrpZCe29RTifKEixXQZ38WheV+i/6YWSzkz3V" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>

<!--navigation-->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light sticky-top">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <a href="" class="navbar-brand float-left"><img src="img/mehrlogo.png" alt=""></a>
</div>
</nav>

</body>
</html>
```

i wanna set my logo to left of browser but it wont 
what the problem

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. Could you provide some more code?

Answer (score 1):

### Bootstrap 4

Note that the Bootstrap4 docs use the `div` tag with the `float` class.
 https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/float/

It won't work for `a` tag.

### Bootstrap less that 4

```html
<a href="" class="navbar-brand float-left">
```

I notice that you have added a `float-left` class in the anchor tag.
As far as I know, there is **no class in Bootstrap as `float-left`**.

You can simply define your own class.

```html
<style>
.float-left {
  float:left;
}
</style>
```

Hope you find it helpful :)

Comment: there float-left float-right and float-none in bootstrap 4...

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/float/ take a look

Comment: also when i open style in html tag and set to float left the logo didnt change

Comment: tnx mr @DivySrivastava for your answer it was helpful

Comment: i wanna set the logo on left and set the links like home and ... to right , not near each other ... what should i do?

Answer (score 1):

This is a bad practice you are doing because under navbar `.container-fluid` not using because this is a container where we have to put some other class like `row` `col` and etc

```
<!--navigation-->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light sticky-top">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <a href="" class="navbar-brand float-left"><img src="img/mehrlogo.png" alt=""></a>
</div>
</nav>
```

The good practice is simply use bootstrap navbar which is available on many resource from the internet the simple navbar example given below and in **bootstrap.min.css** file there are many css class just call class name to use in your project.

If you use this code then no need to set float left and float right just use logo under navbar brand with img tag

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" ></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: this was a practice from youtube which set the container floud in the nav tag ... by the way tnx for your attention and  your answer

Comment: @hossein but this is bad practice you want logo on left side then simply use my answer navbar you no need to write extra css for it

Comment: why my code set logo to right by default and didnt move any more?

Comment: i wanna set the logo on left and set the links like home and ... to right , not near each other

Answer (score 0):

you can use list to do that it is very sample like

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light sticky-top">
<ul class="mr-auto mb-0 pl-0">
    <a href="" class="navbar-brand"><img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/nalabdou/image/upload/v1585057140/user.png" style="width:35px;height:35px"/></a>
</ul>
</nav>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: i wanna set the logo on left and set the links like home and ... to right , not near each other ... what should i do ?

Comment: You create 2end ul with the class ml-auto and you put in it the links hope that would be helpful for you. If this way works hit vote up 

Answer (score 0):

We think your logo is an *i tag*; add this class
`<i class="mr-auto"></i>`
If your logo is not an *i tag*, you can use this piece of code too; tags like *img*,*div* etc.